# How do I change the default language (locality) for new MFC dialogs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

Whenever I create an new dialog in Visual Studio, it sets the Language property to `English (Canada)`, same as my system default.  However, I have a third party MFC library that's rather picky, and decides to crash whenever I try to display such a dialog.  The solution to the crash is to use `English (United States)` as the language.  I would like for my dialogs to default to `English (United States)` when I create them.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official way to do exactly what you want, the default resource language and sublanguage depend on the AFX_TARG_XXX macro, which in turn depends on your system default locale.

However there is kind of hack. **Apply it on your own risk.**

1) Close Visual Studio.

2) Open your resource file in the Notepad.

3) Replace

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_CAN
```

with

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
```

4) Save

This will change the language of all your *existing resources*.

5) Go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\AppWiz\MFC\Application\templates

6) There should be folder named 4105. This is the folder for Canadian resources. Move it to some other place. **Do not delete it** - when you will want to return to Canadian English as your sublanguage, move it back.

7) Open your VS - now US English should be your default sublanguage for all the *new resources*.

Answer (score -1):

I've just changed "string table's language"

`resource view`>>`string table`-> `properties`>> change the `language` you want